# Display image from .map array (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
        setForecast(res2.data.list.map(item => [
          <div className="each_data_point">
            <li className="date_time" key={item.dt_txt}>{`Date & Time: ${item.dt_txt}`}</li>,
            <img className="icon" key={item.weather[0].icon}>{`https://openweathermap.org/img/w/${item.weather[0].icon}.png`}</img>,
            <li className="main_temp" key={item.main.temp}>{`Temp: ${item.main.temp}`}</li>
          </div>
        ]
        ))
        
        
        ......
        
        
        return (
        <div>
        <div className="five_day_forecast">
            <div className="temp_body">
            
            // Display here with Date/Time & Main Temp.
                <p>{forecast}</p>

            </div>
            </div>
```

Is it possible to render an image from array.map() within React. When I run this, the DOM clears completely to white screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `src` in the `img` tag to render image

```
 <img className="icon" key={item.weather[0].icon} src={`https://openweathermap.org/img/w/${item.weather[0].icon}.png`} />
```

And put the key in `div` instead in the children.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are doing it, but setting JSX in your state seems strange.

Try something like this, assuming `res2.data.list` has the list of values.

```
<div className="five_day_forecast">
        <div className="temp_body">
          // Display here with Date/Time & Main Temp.
          <p>
            {res2.data.list && res2.data.list.length >0 && res2.data.list.map(item => [
              <div className="each_data_point">
                <li className="date_time" key={item.dt_txt}>{`Date & Time: ${
                  item.dt_txt
                }`}</li>
                ,
                <img
                  className="icon"
                  key={item.weather[0].icon}
                >{`https://openweathermap.org/img/w/${
                  item.weather[0].icon
                }.png`}</img>
                ,
                <li className="main_temp" key={item.main.temp}>{`Temp: ${
                  item.main.temp
                }`}</li>
              </div>
            ])}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting markup in state is a weird anti-pattern. State is really there to just store *data* not markup. You can use a function to create the JSX from `map`ping over the data.

You should be adding the source of the image to the `src` attribute of the `img` element.

Keys should be added to parent elements.

```
const imgSrc = `https://openweathermap.org/img/w/${item.weather[0].icon}.png`;
<img src={imgSrc} />
```

```js
// `fetch` your data, and add it to state
setForecast(res2.data.list);

// `map` over the data and create the markup
function getMarkup() {

  const imgSrc = `https://openweathermap.org/img/w/${item.weather[0].icon}.png`;

  return forecast.map(item => {
    <div className="each_data_point" key={item.dt_txt}>
      <li className="date_time">{`Date & Time: ${item.dt_txt}`}</li>,
      <img src={imgSrc} className="icon" />,
      <li className="main_temp">{`Temp: ${item.main.temp}`}</li>
    </div>
  });

}

return (
  <div>
    <div className="five_day_forecast">
      <div className="temp_body">

        // Call the function to return the markup
        // build from state
        {getMarkup()}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```